# Image permission windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, windows-8

> Hi
>   I'm trying to display an image in my app but I can't display any Image besides the images that were originally in the app like: logo.png, smallogo.png etc... 
>   but when I choose another image it seems like it has no permission can anybody tel me why?

the following works:

```
<Image x:Name="imag1"  Source="Assets/logo.png" Width="100" Height="300" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

and the folowing doesn't:

```
<Image x:Name="imag1"  Source="Assets/camel.png" Width="100" Height="300" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

needless to say that camel.png is in Assets folder

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on that image?

Comment: Is it possible that camel.png isn't a valid image file, or isn't really in PNG format?

Comment: Did you add the image to Assets in solution explorer?

Comment: Browse into the your project's assets' folder and paste the image there. Now restart the Visual Studio and also try to open the app in blend and drag the image into the grid(or whatever it is you are using)

Comment: make the property of camel.img1 to content and copy always..and check is it working..

Comment: thank you very much.
I guess you have to add it from the properties to the project and not just put it in the right folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you also have `"Camel.png"` added to your project. If you copy it in the `Assets` folder and is not added to your project, it will not work. To verify this, in the solution explorer, open the Assets folder from the folder tree view, and if it's not there, right click on the folder, Add Existing Item and add your image.

Answer (score 0):

hello the problem is about the properties you should have set for camel.png.so properties should be set in properties windows to Content and Copyalways..hope it help you..